# Stopping onclick() events in the same function

Tags: javascript

I have been researching this problem for 2 hours online (including combing though other SO questions) and I can't seem to find an answer, so this is a last resort. For completeness I have added the entire function as it is only just over 100 lines.

Quick Summary : I have a button that the user clicks to start a function named ***measure*** that has an if/else statement. When the condition is true, there are two onclick() functions that are started. (functions *a* and *b*).

When the condition is false (the button is clicked again), the *else* portion is triggered correctly (I verified this)... and I also want the onclick functions to stop. However, they go on forever. I had tried using stopPropogation() but that seems to do nothing and the functions still go on. I have noted in comments where this is.

What am I doing wrong? Skip to the *else* statement to quickly see my problem. (Very bottom).

```
function measure()
{


    if (ims_measure==0) // if variable is 0 (or "off"), set it to 1 (on) and add layers along with onclick() events
    {
        ims_measure=1;
        document.getElementById("cpanel_measure").src = "images/cpanel_measure.png";
        map.setLayoutProperty('measure-points', 'visibility', 'visible');
        map.setLayoutProperty('measure-lines', 'visibility', 'visible');
        measuring_tool_menu = "Measuring Tool (mi.)<br>";


        var distanceContainer = document.getElementById('distance');

        // GeoJSON object to hold our measurement features
        var geojson_measure = {
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'features': []
        };

        // Used to draw a line between points
        var linestring = {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'LineString',
                'coordinates': []
            }
        };


        map.addSource('geojson_measure', {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': geojson_measure
        });

        // Add styles to the map
        map.addLayer({
            id: 'measure-points',
            type: 'circle',
            source: 'geojson_measure',
            paint: {
                'circle-radius': 2,
                'circle-color': '#ffcc33'
            },
            filter: ['in', '$type', 'Point']
        });
        map.addLayer({
            id: 'measure-lines',
            type: 'line',
            source: 'geojson_measure',
            layout: {
                'line-cap': 'round',
                'line-join': 'round'
            },
            paint: {
                'line-color': '#ffcc33',
                'line-width': 2.5
            },
            filter: ['in', '$type', 'LineString']
        });


// First onclick function below (a)

        map.on('click', function(a) {



            var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(a.point, {
                layers: ['measure-points']

            });

            // Remove the linestring from the group
            // So we can redraw it based on the points collection
            if (geojson_measure.features.length > 1)
                geojson_measure.features.pop();

            // Clear the Distance container to populate it with a new value
            distanceContainer.innerHTML = '';

            // If a feature was clicked, remove it from the map
            if (features.length) {
                var id = features[0].properties.id;
                geojson_measure.features = geojson_measure.features.filter(function(point) {
                    return point.properties.id !== id;
                });
            } else {
                var point = {
                    'type': 'Feature',
                    'geometry': {
                        'type': 'Point',
                        'coordinates': [a.lngLat.lng, a.lngLat.lat]
                    },
                    'properties': {
                        'id': String(new Date().getTime())
                    }
                };

                geojson_measure.features.push(point);
            }

            if (geojson_measure.features.length > 1) {
                linestring.geometry.coordinates = geojson_measure.features.map(function(
                point
                ) {
                    return point.geometry.coordinates;
                });

                geojson_measure.features.push(linestring);


                // Populate the distanceContainer with total distance
                var value = document.createElement('pre');
                value.textContent =
                'Total distance: ' +
                turf.length(linestring, {units: 'miles'}).toLocaleString() +'mi';
                distanceContainer.appendChild(value);


            }

            map.getSource('geojson_measure').setData(geojson_measure);
        });



        // Second onclick function below (b)
        map.on('mousemove', function(b) {


            var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(b.point, {
                layers: ['measure-points']
            });
            // UI indicator for clicking/hovering a point on the map - Can't use because inable to change back?!
            //  map.getCanvas().style.cursor = features.length
            //  ? 'pointer'
            //  : 'crosshair';
        });



    }
    else {
        ims_measure=0;

        document.getElementById("cpanel_measure").src = "images/cpanel_measure_dark.png";
        map.setLayoutProperty('measure-points', 'visibility', 'none');
        map.setLayoutProperty('measure-lines', 'visibility', 'none');
        map.removeLayer("measure-lines");
        map.removeLayer("measure-points");
        map.getSource('geojson_measure').setData("");
        map.removeSource("geojson_measure");
        document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML = " ";
        measuring_tool_menu = "null";


       // here is where I wish to stop the onclick functions.
       // I have tried a.stopPropogation(), b.stopPropogation() as well as numerous other methods. None will seemingly do anything
       // as the onclick methods still fires as if I put no code here at all.


        return;
    }




}
```

Comment: If you are simply looking to _turn off_ the click event, use `map.off('click');`

Comment: @Martin I added that, and the events still work as if I did nothing to stop them.

Comment: Your function `b` is not a click handler, but a mousemove handler. So even if you used stopPropogation to stop the _click_ event that you are currently handling in your `measure` function from propagating any further, that would do nothing for the _mousemove_ event …

Comment: @CBroe yeah, I realized I explained it slightly wrong. One is a click event, the other is mousemove.

Answer (score 0):

To remove or detach event function you can use below mentioned functions

Remove OnClick event

```
map.removeEventListener("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

Remove mouse move event

```
map.detachEvent("onmousemove", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Follow [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp) for your reference.

Comment: This does not seem to work. Where would I substitute for functions a and b? I tried a.preventDefault(); and b.preventDefault(); as you instructed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to check if ims_measure==0 inside of functions *a* and *b*, and if it was, then add a.stopPropogation() and b.stopPropogation(). This allowed the function to continue normally but stop the propogation of the listeners when the function was turned "off".